# Rest API : #1062 - duplicate entry for key 'primary'

Tags: rest, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

[image: This My Error .GIF]

I want upload some image to server with rest API using Codeigniter.

But I have a problem after upload image / refresh phpmyadmin on this table.

I know this problem is classic, what I'm already todo:

1. Re-Create the table 2 times.
2. Make **ID** to Autoincrement (actually I'm make it AI at first make table)
3. Not include **ID** on insert operation, and make it AI automatic.
4. I'm already truncate the table 2 times

but nothing change anything, at I'm refresh page phpmyadmin this error always appear.

What's my mistake ?

Thanks

If you think my error because my code Rest-API, here's my code:

**Controller**:

```
public function upload_post()
{
    // $config['max_size']  = '100';
    // $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    // $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $msgCreated = ['status' => true, 'message' => 'Image Has Been Upload'];
    $msgFailCreated = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'Failed to Upload Image !'];
    $config['upload_path'] = './image/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
        $this->set_response($msgFailCreated, 404);
    } else {
        $info = $this->upload->data();
        $image_path = base_url("image/" . $info['raw_name'] . $info['file_ext']);
        $data = [
            "name_image" => $this->input->post('name_image'),
            "image" => $image_path
        ];
        if ($this->mahasiswa->insertImage($data)) {
            $this->set_response($msgCreated, 201);
        } else {
            $this->set_response($msgFailCreated, 400);
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
//? Membuat Upload Image
    public function insertImage($data){
        return $this->db->insert('image', $data);
    }
```

Comment: Have you try to empty the record (`truncate`)?

Comment: @HastaDhana not yet,  i will, wait a second.

Comment: @HastaDhana error still appear, this error disturb me but the data success insert to table. but error always appear at refresh the page

Comment: Have you try restarting the web server service and/or mysql service?

Comment: @HastaDhana i restart my pc and the error dissappear.